# How do you declare a variable in Denodo?

Tags: denodo

I'm having trouble declaring a variable in my query to use with Denodo.

I've tried writing it using sql syntax, but I get an error with "declare".

```sql
declare @var1 varchar(6) = 'table1'

select column_name, column_description
from view('pb', '@var1')
order by column_name
```

I expect this to run with the variable "var1" but I get  error code 1100 with a message: "Syntax Error: Exception parsing query near declare".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables in Denodo with SETVAR('', '', '', ''). But this will only work with column names or conditions in where clauses. I have tested it and it does not work with view names.

Example:

```
select SETVAR('columnname','foo');
select GETVAR('columnname', 'text', 'asdf') from foobar
```

this returns the foo column of the foobar table

This does not work:

```
select SETVAR('tablename','foobar');
select * from GETVAR('tablename', 'text', 'asdf')
```

I don't think using a variable as table name is possible in denodo. You might need to do that in a script while writing the query.

Comment: It is possible to avoid giving default value `asdf`?